# React setState spread operator not supported in Chrome 40

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using chrome 40 which does not support spread operator. I know updating to latest version solve this problem but issue here is I cant update it.

How to rewrite this code without spread operator?

```
this.setState({...card});
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly `this.setState(card)` is equal to `this.setState({...card})` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this example, it is just `this.setState(card)`. I.e., if `card = {col1: 1}`, then `{...card}` is converted to `{col1: 1}` – itself:

```
this.setState( card );
```

[**Demonstration**](http://www.es6fiddle.net/ilmeczf9/)

If you want to use it with non-empty object, you can use `Object.assign`:

```
this.setState( Object.assign({col0: 0}, card) );
```

Comment: demonstration link is broken and also I do not understand how to assign multiple key value pairs to the state at once, i would like more explanation.